# How to convert decimal to integer in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, casting

The input xml includes the following element:

```
<numberOfPayments>14.0</numberOfPayments>
```

I need to convert the number to integer, with following limitations:

- the XML is coming from an external source, I cant ask them to send me the integer
- it has to be an XPath, I can't use any other language

Answer (score 6):

You can use `round()`. The xpath query would be:

```
round(/numberOfPayments/text())
```

or if you are only interested in the integer part without rounding you can use `floor()`:

```
floor(/numberOfPayments/text())
```

Comment: Yeah, but the first will give you `15` for `14.6` the latter `14`.

Comment: In my case I'm getting an integer in decimal form. The external system supposed to send me an integer, but their API is turning it into NN.00